# Is message passing between multiple content scripts possible without using the background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

When migrating a Chrome Extension to Manifest v3 we are getting rid of the background script and are instead using service workers.

The problem is that we previously sent messages from multiple content scripts to another content script through the background script, and this is no longer possible because in Manifest v3 the background script will become inactive after a while.

Is it possible to send messages between multiple content scripts without using the background script?

This is an example of how the content scripts are setup, sender.js is available in multiple iframes while receiver.js only is present in the top document.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["receiver.js"],
      "all_frames": false,
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    },
    {
      "js": ["sender.js"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The service worker is still a background script so you can and should use it the same way to relay messages. It will wake up when you send a message. If it doesn't it's a bug in ManifestV3 so maybe you should keep using ManifestV2. P.S. Although you can send messages between frames directly via parent.postMessage but it can be intercepted by the web page and it can break its functionality due to an unexpected message.

Comment: @wOxxOm All right thanks! Yes it may very well be a bug in MV3. I will investigate it some more.

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages from contents scripts to other content scripts with `chrome.storage.local`, no service worker required.

Proof of concept:

- The counter has two purposes:

  - Allows content scripts to distinguish their own messages from other content scripts' messages.
  - Guarantees that `chrome.storage.onChanged` always fires, even if the data hasn't changed.
- You need to execute the entire code inside the async function every time you send a message.
- You could also use random numbers instead of a counter.

  - Advantage: You don't have to read the old counter value from storage.
  - Disadvantage: You need to make sure there are no collisions.
- I don't know if the "event doesn't wake up the service worker" bug can occur in content scripts.
- Instead of chrome.storage.local, you could use chrome.storage.session, but you'd need to set the access level: [Storage areas > storage.session](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#storage-areas)

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Content Script Messaging with Storage",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

`content_script.js`

```
let counter = -1;

function storage_on_changed(changes, areaName) {
    if (changes?.message?.newValue?.counter == counter) {
        console.log("The message came from this content script", changes);
    }
    else {
        console.log("The message came from another content script", changes);
    }
}

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(storage_on_changed);

(async () => {
    let { message } = await chrome.storage.local.get("message");
    if (message === undefined) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    else {
        counter = message.counter + 1;
    }
    await chrome.storage.local.set({ message: {counter, data: document.URL} });
})();
```