chrome.tabs.query missing some tabs when opening tabs quickly
I am working on an MV3 extension and I am trying to resolve a performance issue.
When a tab opens, a content script is injected into the page (via a manifest setting), the content script then sends a message to the service worker to say the content script is ready.
The service worker then tries to message all the open tabs to let them know that a new tab has opened, and it uses chrome.tabs.query to know what tabs are open.
However, when I call chrome.tabs.query it isn't giving me back all the tabs I'd expect it to if I open the tabs in quick succession. When opening the tabs and loading a page really fast, 4 out of 5 times it will give back the correct tabs, and quite consistently 1 of the 5 times I call the method it misses out a tab.
I could keep track of all the tabs open myself, but I would like to have thought that I could rely on Chrome to give me back the correct information when I query what tabs exist.
  private findTabsAbleToReceiveMessages(): Promise<Tab[]> {
    return chrome.tabs.query({ url: '<all_urls>' });
  }

Is this a bug with Chrome, or is there a fix or something I can do differently to resolve this?
The following is my logs
22:32:56.581 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] 'READY' message received
22:32:56.585 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] Sending 'READY' response
22:32:56.591 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '9D248962-5B60-4310-BDFB-35A65FB87F94' to all tabs Object
22:32:56.591 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '9D248962-5B60-4310-BDFB-35A65FB87F94' to tab '1882799386' CommandMessage Object
22:32:57.507 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] 'READY' message received
22:32:57.507 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] Sending 'READY' response
22:32:57.508 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '83464DA0-8E2B-422C-95C5-79C8375EBA3E' to all tabs Object
22:32:57.508 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '83464DA0-8E2B-422C-95C5-79C8375EBA3E' to tab '1882799386' CommandMessage Object
22:32:58.378 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] 'READY' message received
22:32:58.378 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] Sending 'READY' response
22:32:58.379 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'CAC2B875-33C1-4DF1-9B23-0A8FB4D1A198' to all tabs Object Object
22:32:58.379 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'CAC2B875-33C1-4DF1-9B23-0A8FB4D1A198' to tab '1882799386' CommandMessage Object
22:32:58.379 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'CAC2B875-33C1-4DF1-9B23-0A8FB4D1A198' to tab '1882799387' CommandMessage Object
22:32:59.322 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] 'READY' message received
22:32:59.322 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] Sending 'READY' response
22:32:59.325 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'C11A9108-2669-48CA-82C1-A2390FEBBF01' to all tabs Object Object Object
22:32:59.325 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'C11A9108-2669-48CA-82C1-A2390FEBBF01' to tab '1882799386' CommandMessage Object
22:32:59.325 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'C11A9108-2669-48CA-82C1-A2390FEBBF01' to tab '1882799387' CommandMessage Object
22:32:59.325 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'C11A9108-2669-48CA-82C1-A2390FEBBF01' to tab '1882799388' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.222 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] 'READY' message received
22:33:00.223 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] Sending 'READY' response
22:33:00.226 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '75C9780E-F2BD-4B66-A622-AF8E8B3ECC5D' to all tabs Object Object Object Object Object
22:33:00.226 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '75C9780E-F2BD-4B66-A622-AF8E8B3ECC5D' to tab '1882799386' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.227 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '75C9780E-F2BD-4B66-A622-AF8E8B3ECC5D' to tab '1882799387' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.227 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '75C9780E-F2BD-4B66-A622-AF8E8B3ECC5D' to tab '1882799388' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.228 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '75C9780E-F2BD-4B66-A622-AF8E8B3ECC5D' to tab '1882799389' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.228 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '75C9780E-F2BD-4B66-A622-AF8E8B3ECC5D' to tab '1882799390' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.856 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] 'READY' message received
22:33:00.856 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] Sending 'READY' response
22:33:00.880 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'E69A7A61-C620-4873-9683-64784FA26771' to all tabs Object Object Object Object Object Object
22:33:00.880 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'E69A7A61-C620-4873-9683-64784FA26771' to tab '1882799386' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.880 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'E69A7A61-C620-4873-9683-64784FA26771' to tab '1882799387' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.880 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'E69A7A61-C620-4873-9683-64784FA26771' to tab '1882799388' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.881 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'E69A7A61-C620-4873-9683-64784FA26771' to tab '1882799389' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.881 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'E69A7A61-C620-4873-9683-64784FA26771' to tab '1882799390' CommandMessage Object
22:33:00.890 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message 'E69A7A61-C620-4873-9683-64784FA26771' to tab '1882799391' CommandMessage Object
22:33:01.478 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] 'READY' message received
22:33:01.478 logger.ts:44 [Info] [ReadyCommand] Sending 'READY' response
22:33:01.500 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '8634A269-8CE8-4CE1-AEBE-B3DA16658E85' to all tabs Object Object Object Object Object Object Object
22:33:01.500 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '8634A269-8CE8-4CE1-AEBE-B3DA16658E85' to tab '1882799386' CommandMessage Object
22:33:01.500 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '8634A269-8CE8-4CE1-AEBE-B3DA16658E85' to tab '1882799387' CommandMessage Object
22:33:01.500 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '8634A269-8CE8-4CE1-AEBE-B3DA16658E85' to tab '1882799388' CommandMessage Object
22:33:01.500 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '8634A269-8CE8-4CE1-AEBE-B3DA16658E85' to tab '1882799389' CommandMessage Object
22:33:01.500 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '8634A269-8CE8-4CE1-AEBE-B3DA16658E85' to tab '1882799390' CommandMessage Object
22:33:01.501 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '8634A269-8CE8-4CE1-AEBE-B3DA16658E85' to tab '1882799391' CommandMessage Object
22:33:01.501 logger.ts:47 [Debug] [MessageSender] Sending message '8634A269-8CE8-4CE1-AEBE-B3DA16658E85' to tab '1882799392' CommandMessage Object

What should have been logged is after each ready command the number of Object keywords increases by one, like so (some logging removed for brevity):
ready
sending message to all tabs Object
ready
sending message to all tabs Object Object
ready
sending message to all tabs Object Object Object
ready
sending message to all tabs Object Object Object Object
ready
sending message to all tabs Object Object Object Object Object
ready
sending message to all tabs Object Object Object Object Object Object


The problem is not evident from the description and code you've provided.
It may have to do with when you call findTabsAbleToReceiveMessages . For example, if you do something like whle(something) { findTabsAbleToReceiveMessages(); chrome.tabs.create({ .. }); }, the number of tabs that you get when findTabsAbleToReceiveMessages is resolved may not be equal to the number of times you've called chrome.tabs.create({ .. }) beforehand.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you may have better luck using something like chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(..)

If nothing else works: Instead of using chrome.tabs.sendMessage(), you could send a message to all tabs with chrome.storage.local.set() - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75219957/is-message-passing-between-multiple-content-scripts-possible-without-using-the-b/75237122#75237122 - Side note: findTabsAbleToReceiveMessages() can return the result of chrome.tabs.query() directly, it doesn't need to be wrapped in a promise constructor ("explicit promise construction antipattern")

The number of times findTabsAbleToReceiveMessages is called directly correlates to the number of times a tab is opened, this is only the case because when the content script is loaded it sends a message to the service worker and the service worker then calls findTabsAbleToReceiveMessages, given the content script has been able to message the service worker, Chrome should be able to return the tab in the query but it doesn't.

This whole thing came about when I started tracking down why sometimes some code executes in the tabs and sometimes it doesn't. The code needs both the content script and service worker to be ready before it can be called, but it isn't always called, and the root cause of this is because Chrome sometimes misses a tab when querying them.
